# I cant import packagens on .py file (Anaconda enviroment on VSCode)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, dll, anaconda

I'm using jupyter extension on VSCode with an Anaconda enviroment and Python works just fine on .ipynb format.

*Imports working just fine on .ipynb files*
[image: Imports working just fine on .ipynb files]

But when I try to import any package in a .py file I have an error, even though I'm using the same Python interpreter:

*Imports not working on .py files*
[image: Imports not working on .py files]

Full error msg:

```
    PS C:\Users\Raul> & G:/anaconda3/envs/PBTeste/python.exe "c:/Users/Raul/Desktop/OneDrive/DI ROCHA/Projeto Bollinger/projeto_bollinger.py"
G:\anaconda3\envs\PBTeste\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py:148: UserWarning: mkl-service package failed to import, therefore Intel(R) MKL initialization ensuring its correct out-of-the box operation under condition when Gnu OpenMP had already been loaded by Python process is not assured. Please install mkl-service package, 
see http://github.com/IntelPython/mkl-service
  from . import _distributor_init
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\anaconda3\envs\PBTeste\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>  
    from . import multiarray
  File "G:\anaconda3\envs\PBTeste\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\multiarray.py", line 12, in <module>
    from . import overrides
  File "G:\anaconda3\envs\PBTeste\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\overrides.py", line 7, in <module>  
    from numpy.core._multiarray_umath import (
ImportError: DLL load failed: Não foi possível encontrar o módulo especificado.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/Raul/Desktop/OneDrive/DI ROCHA/Projeto Bollinger/projeto_bollinger.py", line 11, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "G:\anaconda3\envs\PBTeste\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 150, in <module>
    from . import core
  File "G:\anaconda3\envs\PBTeste\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 48, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError:

IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!

Importing the numpy C-extensions failed. This error can happen for
many reasons, often due to issues with your setup or how NumPy was
installed.

We have compiled some common reasons and troubleshooting tips at:

    https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html

Please note and check the following:

  * The Python version is: Python3.7 from "G:\anaconda3\envs\PBTeste\python.exe"
  * The NumPy version is: "1.21.5"

and make sure that they are the versions you expect.
Please carefully study the documentation linked above for further help.

Original error was: DLL load failed: Não foi possível encontrar o módulo especificado.
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are three suggestions that I hope will help you:

1. Import these packages in the `__init__.py` file in the folder where your current `.py` file is located.
2. Specify the package path with the following code at the beginning of the file:

```
import sys
sys.path.append(".\mainfloder\projectfloder")
```

3. Use the following code to specify the package path in the `setting.json` file:

```
    "python.analysis.extraPaths":[
        "c:\\workspace\\pythontest\\.venv\\lib\\site-packages",
        "./src",    
    ]
```